# Cosine Interpolation with Integers

Tags: interpolation, integer, trigonometry

Ok so I've been looking into interpolation lately. Sadly almost every article I've read only discusses interpolation at a decimal level 0.0 to 1.0 to be exact. I would like to interpolate whole number integers regardless of how big they are or if there negative or whatever. I've accomplished this with linear interpolation:

```
public int interpolate(int y1, int y2, int length, int x){
    return y1 + x * (y2 - y1) / (length-1);
}
```

However I'm stuck with cosine interpolation. [This](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) great article talks about cosine interpolation however it's on a system of numbers from 0.0 to 1.0 as stated above. Here is what I have so far:

```
public int interpolate(int y1, int y2, int length, int x){
    int v = (int)(y2 - Mathf.Cos(x * 3.1415f))/2;
    return (y1 + x * (y2 - y1) / (length-1)) * v;
}
```

It doesn't work though it returns an almost random number with no real direction making it not smooth at all. This is where I need your help. Long story short: How do I make a cosine interpolation function that deals with integers?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the article that you linked to. It's not saying that its system of numbers is from 0.0 to 1.0; rather, it's saying that you should set mu = 0 when you're at the first endpoint and mu = 1 when you're at the endpoint. So, if your endpoints are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), and you want to interpolate at x, then mu = x1+(x-x1)/(x2-x1).

Comment: @ruakh shouldn't that be mu = (x-x1)/(x2-x1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of cos θ varies from 1 to -1 to 1 as its input ranges from [0, 2π]. We need something from [0, 1].  So

1. Limit the domain to [0, π] to limit codomain to [1, -1]
2. Subtract from 1, for codomain to be [0, 2]
3. Divide by 2 to get a codomain of [0, 1]

You've get a nice function that goes from 0 to 1.  The rest is transforming the argument.

Essentially you need

```
(int) ((1 - cos(pi*x / (length-1)))/2 * (y2-y1)+y2)
```

Comment: It works however it seems to flip the numbers around. If I set y1 to say 20 and y2 to 50 then the result will be an interpolation of 50 to 20 not 20 to 50.

Comment: Then just switch y1 and y2 around. I've edited the formula for you.